# Konya kimi wa boku no mono

Tags: translation, meaning

I got this from one Japanese drama (if I heard right) 'konya kimi wa boku no mono' .  Does this mean: 'tonight you are mine'  ?

Comment: Hahah yes!  Good job making me giggle yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does and your translation is spot-on. (This type of question can also be asked in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language).)

Comment: Might also say "Tonight you belong to me."  but the essence is still there